# Alterando cor de uma div ao clicar a primeira vez e mostrar um alerta ao clicar a segunda vez

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Estou tento dificuldades em criar um código que é simples, preciso que ao clicar em uma `div` ela mude de cor e ao clicar pela segunda vez ela abra um `alert` informando o nome da cor.

Pode ser em jQuery ou js

```js
$(document).click(function() {
  $(".cor").css("background", "blue");

});

$(".cor").click(function() {
  alert("HTML: " + $("#test").html());

});
```

Comment: Podes explicar melhor a lógica das cores? de onde vem a cor? cada div vai ter uma cor diferente?

Comment: Não sei fazer em Javascript, mas minha dica seria criar os padrões de cores em CSS, quando desejar trocar a cor, troque a classe CSS definida na DIV; já para apresentar um `alert`, declare uma variável que sirva de contador e ao clicar, incremente esta variável e verifique pelo valor dela, se deve ou não apresentar o alert...
Aqui você não indica a linguagem que está utilizando, ajudaria no caso de postar um exemplo!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Segue um exemplo, caso restar alguma dúvida coloque no comentário.

```js
$(function(){
  $('div').click(function(){
    console.log($(this).css('background-color'))
    if($(this).css('background-color') == 'rgb(204, 204, 204)'){
      $(this).css('background-color','rgb(255, 0, 0)');
    }else{
      alert('Cor da div : ' + $(this).css('background-color'));
    }
  });
});
```

```css
div{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: rgb(204,204,204);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```